# Unable to use access *token* to consume Azure API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We followed below steps to consume Azure API, but unable to accessing because of authentication problem:

Step 1 : Got the authorization code.

Step 2 : Got Access token by using authorization code.

Step 3 : When we are trying to access the below API, we are getting error which is mentioned below.

> > We made get call with below url.

API URL : https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2014-04-01

```
Exception : 
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationTokenAudience",
    "message": "The access token has been obtained from wrong audience or resource 'c115688e-4729-4439-b741-b61ae10a8920'. It should exactly match (including forward slash) with one of the allowed audiences 'management.azure.com'."
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you included authorization request header in `Authorization: Bearer {access token}` form in your request? Please share your code as well.

Comment: Issue has been fixed. Actually, I was getting authentication token with different parameter combinations which was wrong.